# Android webview detect specific page change

Tags: android

I have an android webview app with user authentication, the app allows users to register their devices by collecting the device's android id. When a user runs the mobile app, it will check if the mobile device is registered then validates the login details associated with the registered device. All works as designed with no issue.

My problem is that when the PHP session expires, users will be directed to the login page. If the user closes the app and re-open it, it will log the user without having to re-enter the login details. PHP session time-out can not be changed due to company policy.

I would like to know if I could detect the login page URL change and send the device android id with the login page URL similar to the app startup process. So, when the PHP session expires, users will be automatically logged back in without having to re-enter their login credentials.

Here is the current code I am using, some irrelevant codes have been removed to reduce the code lines. This is my first android app, and I have very limited experience when it comes to mobile programming and I have been searching for the last couple of day without any luck. Help and directions are highly appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    boolean isConnct = false;
    // code here to check internet connection

    // end of internet connection code

    if (isConnct){
        // internet is ok
        final WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(webView.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
                // show error message
            }

        });
        // using setWebChromeClient to enable javascript
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
                // js confirm code
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
                // js alert code
            }
        });
        // enable javascript and other settings
        String url = "https://www.domainname/login/" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    } else {
        // show error message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try override [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) method in `WebViewClient`, check your login URL and start your auto-login from there

another approach is checking cookies expiration time, you may use [CookieManager.getInstance()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager) for this

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried that but couldn't get it to work. Am I able to use ShouldOverrideUrlLoading to check if the directed URL is the login page, then attach the android device id with the login url before loading the login page url?

Comment: exacly, you may return `false` when login page is detected, this will force passing user there and webpage won't start loading. just before returning `false` start your custom login procedure with `AndroidID` and when success then pass user to some home page or page on which he was before PHP sesion logout (cookie timeout) - in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` you can call `webView.getUrl()` to get to know where user is currently and store this value. after proper custom log-in just refresh page by loading same URL

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, and it seems working as expected, when PHP session expires, registered devices will be redirected to the index page with new session without having to re-enter user credentials.

If there is a logout button then you need to consider adding different procedure for the logout to allow users to logout and re-direct to login page.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    //hide loading image
                    findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(ImageView.GONE);
                    //show webview
                    findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(webView.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
                    // show error message
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url.contentEquals("https://www.domainme/login")){
                        String url2 = "https://www.domainme/login/" + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                        webView.loadUrl(url2);
                        return true;
                    }else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

// code truncated

}
```